# How to find the name of the user that has been logged in the longest?

Tags: linux, terminal

I need to determine the user who has been logged in to the Linux server for the longest time. Can't come up with the right commando. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: use command: last

Answer (score 0):

Command `who` can tell you since when someone is logged in.

Command `w` also presents that information somewhat truncated.

Command `awk '{ print $22 }' /proc/$PID/stat` will give you the start time (in *jiffies*[0]) of a process, so you can get this for the users' shells/ssh sessions and do the calculation.

I'm sure there are other ways.

[0]: see [Converting jiffies to milli seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731463/converting-jiffies-to-milli-seconds).